# Find length of longest palindrome. Is it possible to do this without an extra data structure?

Tags: java, algorithm

The problem is to find the LENGTH of the longest palindrome, not the palindrome itself. I used a Map for this, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without using other data structures.

Also, how long does this algorithm take to run?

```
public class Solution {
    public int longestPalindrome(String s) {
        boolean oddExists = false; // checks if there are odd characters
        int length = s.length(); // assumes that highest possible length can be the original length
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); // counts characters
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if (!map.containsKey(s.charAt(i))){map.put(s.charAt(i), 0);}
            map.put(s.charAt(i), map.get(s.charAt(i)) + 1);
        }

        for (char x : map.keySet()){ // go through all the characters
            if (map.get(x) % 2 != 0){ // if there are odd characters, length of palindrome decreases
                oddExists = true; // odd character found
                length--; // length decreased
            }
        }

        if (oddExists){length++;} // one odd character can be allowed to be at the center of the palindrome
        return length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean to find the length of the longest palindrome that can be formed using the characters in a string?  Or are you searching within a string for the longest subsequence that is a palindrome?  What do you want to return for the string `"aabbcc"`?

Comment: You can do it by getting the `char[]` and sort it. Don't know if you consider that "using another data structure". Performance of your code is _O(n)_. Using sort would be _O(n_ log _n)_.

Comment: @JimGarrison If you look at the code, you'll see that it is complete, and calculates the length of the longest palindrome possible using only the characters of `s`, using each character at most once.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public int longestPalindrome(String s) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    int length = s.length();
    char[] map = new char[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        ++map[s.charAt(i) - 'a'];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
        if ((map[i] & 1) != 0)
            --length;
    if (length < s.length())
        ++length;
    return length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. It does not use any maps.

```
public class Algo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        /*
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("a"));
        System.out.println(isPalindrome(""));
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("aba"));
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("akka"));
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("lolz"));
        */

        System.out.println(longestPalindrome("lolz"));
        System.out.println(longestPalindrome("akka"));
        System.out.println(longestPalindrome("elephant"));
        System.out.println(longestPalindrome("attari"));

    }

    public static int longestPalindrome(String x){
        if (isPalindrome(x)) {
            return x.length();
        } else {
            //return 0;
            return Math.max(longestPalindrome(x.substring(1)),  
                   longestPalindrome(x.substring(0, x.length() - 1)));
        }
    }



    public static boolean isPalindrome(String x){
        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = x.length() - 1;

        while(startIndex < endIndex){
            if (x.charAt(startIndex) != x.charAt(endIndex)) {
                return false;
            }

            startIndex++;
            endIndex--;

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```